# create a list of lists where the length of the list is mentioned in another column

Tags: python, pandas

My df looks like this;

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'count':[1,2,4,5,8,1,3]})
```

How do I create a new column called 'lists' which holds a random list where the length of the list is the value in the 'count' column? Something like this...

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'count':[1,2,4,5,8,1,3],
                     'lists': [[1],[34,56],[25,65,1,4],[33,37,89,12,11],[45,56,78,98,12,2,3,4],[234],[23,456,765]]
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This would be very inefficient

Comment: But I've got into a situation which demands me to

Comment: @EdChum Yes. I guess this is very inefficient for a df to handle

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
data['list'] = data.applymap(lambda x: random.sample(xrange(100), x))
```

Alternatively,

```
data['list'] = data['count'].apply(lambda x: pd.np.random.random_integers(1, 100, x) )
```

Comment: how about generating a list of random numbers?

Comment: @richie see the updated answer. And, ofcourse, you need to import random